# updating db file in existing android project

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I recently accepted a contract job to develop for an Android Application publisher.  They wanted me to update an existing android project to allow for a trial mode.  To achieve this, I had to make changes to the schema of the databse being used by the application.

When I was using the emulator, I was able to make changes to the database by pull out the application's database file from the data\data.... directory, using the file explorer in ddms perspective in eclipse. I then edited the database, and pushed it back in to the same directory. This worked fine and I was able to use the updated database in the emulator.

However, when I had to begin using a real android device (its a Nexus 7), I ran into an issue.  I am not able to update the database as I had done before, because the data folder is not accessible.  This broke all of the code utilizing the changed to the database's schema.

At this point, I don't even understand where this original copy of the database is coming from. There is no copy of the database in any of the applauncher or libarary's subdirectories either.  I have unpacked the apk file for the app launcher and found no copy. I also unpacked the jar file for the library project that the applauncher uses.  Please forgive me if I am omitting any necessary information.  I am very new to android development. I will gladly provide any other information that maybe useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Android application wishing to use a sqlite database usually extends the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class. At the minimum the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class takes 4 arguments - context, database's name, cursor factory and a database version. The database would be created by Android (with the name you provided) the first time you try to open a connection to the database (using either `getReadableDatabase` or `getWritableDatabase`) and the `onCreate` method is called. Here is where you would execute statements on the `sqliteDatabase` object you get passed, to create the tables you want.

Whenever you want to change your tables' schema, you bump up the version number you pass into SQLiteOpenHelper's constructor. `onUpgrade` method will be called for you once the system sees that the version number has been increased (if you pass in a smaller version number than what was already present, `onDowngrade` would be called) and you can execute all the migration statements on the sqliteDatabase object passed to you

Answer (score 0):

We'll not have permission to see actual device SQLite DataBase. For reading and updating the device sqlite db use the below library
[use this library to read/modify the device database](https://github.com/sanathp/DatabaseManager_For_Android)